# What are all the debugging tools available for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, debugging

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of all tools for debugging iPhone apps, and any online resources relating to them.

Answer (score 5):

How about the tools that come with Xcode, like gdb and Instruments?

This will also help: http://google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+iphone+apps

Comment: Or even just Xcode itself - syntax checker, static analyzer, breakpoints, etc...

Comment: @Tim +1 - the static analyzer has saved my bacon so many times!

Comment: Agreed, the static analyzer is always a huge help.

Comment: +1 for the link to Google! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good Apple document entitled: "[Xcode Debugging Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)"

Answer (score 0):

I assume this questions is about Xcode debugging. However i am developing web based iPhone apps using the like IUI and iWebkit etc. Normally for web development i would use Firefox/Firebug but for iPhone the [Webkit](http://webkit.org/) is better (IMHO) and the javascript debugging is excellent. I also use the iPhone simulator rather then needing to deploy the code to a server.

Answer (score 0):

I've incorporated the following tools into my Xcode pipeline:

[GHUnit](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) - Unit testing which can run on the simulator and devices, and allows debugging.
[OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/) - Mocking framework for use in the unit tests.
[Appledoc](http://www.gentlebytes.com/freeware/appledoc/) - For creating more apple like API docs and including them into XCode.

Answer (score -1):

WiCon wireless console helps to send debug messages to iPhone/iPad screen from another iPhone/iPad or from a computer. I use it to track my apps for example if the connection to a usual debugger is not available or if I need to take care of a long process (WiCon gives sound alarms on debug messages and I don't need to stare at screen to notice messages).

Comment: Please add a link that points to a WiCon download page, for it is difficult to find on the Internet.

Comment: Here it is: https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/wicon/id619415172?mt=8